# Opening most recent txt file

Tags: c#, file-io

Having a bit of trouble I am trying to have the very most recent txt file open.
i am using a button and i need the txt file  to open in a catch
thing is there is over a few hundred text files, and i need the last file by date and time

//..............Updated.............//

Here is a better example of what my file looks like
there is a few extra logs and they update contently

```
commandlog2012081410   (2012-08-14 /  01:01)
commandlog2012081411   (2012-08-14 /  10:30)
commandlog2012081412   (2012-08-14 /  12:36)
Sample2012082207   (2012-08-22   /  02:12)
Sample2012082208   (2012-08-22   /  06:28)
Sample2012082209   (2012-08-22   /  09:14)
faillog2012075671   (2012-07-17  /  01:20)
faillog2012075672   (2012-07-17  /  08:00)
faillog2012075673   (2012-07-17  /  09:00)
chargedlog203416771   (2012-07-05 /  20:36)
chargedlog203416772   (2012-07-05 /  21:20)
chargedlog203416773   (2012-07-05 /  22:42)
vanishlog2012324795   (2012-07-21 / 17:00)
vanishlog2012324796   (2012-07-21 / 19:31)
vanishlog2012324797   (2012-07-21 / 20:28)
debuglog123131231    (2012-08-22 / 05:10)
debuglog123131232    (2012-08-22 / 06:12)
debuglog123131233    (2012-08-22 / 09:14)
droplogg12313131    (2012-08-06 / 10:10)
droplogg12313132    (2012-08-06 / 16:41)
exitlog123131313     (2012-08-22  /   01:01)
exitlog123131314     (2012-08-22  /   01:12)
exitlog123131315     (2012-08-22  /   09:14)
log201123131     (2012-08-22  / 09:12)
log201123132     (2012-08-22  / 09:14)
```

i need to open //Sample2012082209   (2012-08-22   /  09:14)//
as you can see a few other txt files end at the same time at the same date is it even possible to pick out that one file and open it

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message.ToString());
         (Open newest Sample txt file here)
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use Linq and [`File.GetLastAccessTime` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getlastaccesstime.aspx)  to get the last openend file:

```
var openedFiles = from fName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.txt")
                 orderby File.GetLastAccessTime(fName) descending
                 select new FileInfo(fName);
if (openedFiles.Any())
{
    var lastOpenedFile = openedFiles.First();
}
```

[`Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.txt")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) returns only `txt`-files in a given directory.

**Edit**: I'm afraid the question is still not clear, even if you've edited it and you've written several comments. But if you only want files that starts with a given name (f.e. *"Sample"*), you on ly have to adjust the searchpattern of `EnumerateFiles`:

```
var name = "Sample";
var openedFiles = from fName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, name + "*.txt")
                  orderby File.GetLastAccessTime(fName) descending
                  select new FileInfo(fName);
```

Comment: wouldn't that get the last .txt files in the folder. The files i need is near the center of the folder its like an error log 
the error log .txt file's numbers will always change but the name will always be the same (Sample000123,Sample000124)
i would like to get the last .txt file of Sample

Comment: @MikeSmith: the query orders all txt-files in a folder by access time descending. That means the first file is the file that was last accessed. Is that what you need? _" I am trying to have the very most recent txt file open"_

Comment: i updated my original post if it helps there are alot of logs sometimes they write at the same time only the name stays the same 
is there a way to open (sample(00000000) at the last date and time

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not clear. You want to open the last log that staarts with a given name(f.e. `Sample...`)? Or do you want to get the file which was accessed last(as my answer)?

Comment: yes i want to open the last log that starts with the given name (Sample) the numbers after the text will change every time it updates

Comment: But there are three files that start with "Sample". All have the _same_ name with the _same_ number, is that a typo? And what is the rule for taking "Sample..." instead of "commandlog..."? And are these files all in the same folder or in different?

Comment: Sample2012082009   (2012-08-22   /  02:12)
Sample2012082132   (2012-08-22   /  06:28)
Sample2012082546   (2012-08-22   /  09:14)
Should be like that sorry,files are in the same folder Can i take Sample instead of commandlog ?
if file name begins with Sample then open newest in directory 
would something like that work

Comment: @MikeSmith: Edited my answer. It now selects only txt-files that start with  given a name(in this case _"Sample"_).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class DirectoryInfo to get information about a given directory. From there you can get the files and with the class FileInfo get information about things like creation date. Here's an example:

```
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
    foreach (FileInfo file in dirInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        DateTime creationdate = file.CreationTime;
    }
```

Just comment if you need more info